# How send data with location to a server in real time? Did i do it right?

Tags: php, android, server, location

I need to make a system where android application will send the user's location to the server in real time. Then on the website (on the same server) you will be able to watch how the user (with app) travels. Just like you can follow the food supplier from uber eats.

The project is currently made and works very well, but I am not convinced if I did it correctly?

Now the android application reads the user's location every 1 second and sends it to the server using the POST method. For example: mydomain.com/gps.php?usertoken=XXX&latitude=XXX&longitude=XXX. Every time when a php file gets this data, it saves it in the MySQL database. That's all.

Now the user visiting the site can see the locations users with app on the map (location from the database).

Is this the right solution? Should I not use any other methods? There may be several dozen users in the future, will such a system be efficient? I kindly ask for some advice. I am a beginner programmer.

Code in gps.php file for android app:

```
$lat = $_POST['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['longitude'];
$login = $_POST['usertoken'];

//save location to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
$db->query("UPDATE users SET latitude='$lat', longitude='$long' WHERE login='$login'");
$db->close();
```

Comment: you should use ajax with `set interval()` or `websockets` to solve this

Comment: using ajax is fine, 1 second updates is overkill unless you need per second updates serverside, which most of the time you dont (not sure about android but in chrome, it moans if re-query more then once a min), the php code is wide open to SQL injection, which is a bigger issue to fix before adding realtime updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets could be a solution for you. They allow you to establish a bidirectional connection between Server and Client. Perfect for applications with a lot of "traffic"
caused by the smaller overhead it will produce. The ability to push data from the Server to the Client is also pretty neat for your application since it will allow you to update the Client whenever
something happens on the Server.

https://socket.io/ is a pretty neat library for Client and Server. For the MySQL part you could use something like node.js and its mysql package

https://nodejs.org/en/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think, your rest api(http) network call is not wrong. It is a right solution in most case.

**But I think you need to keep your database connection in your php proxy server.**

Because server is always on going in general.

And reconnect to database in each query is expensive work.